# use variable contet in a literal/const template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose

```
template <int16_t value>
struct x;
```

Somewhere in the code, there is:

```
int16_t var;
```

I would like to use `var` contents as `value`.

Is it someway, in C++11 or C++14, possible?

TIA!

Comment: Only possible if `var` is a copile-time-constant. Declare it `constexpr`.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to DarkFalcon's answer, you may build a *jump table*.

Assuming something like:

```
template <std::int16_t value>
struct x
{
    static void f() { std::cout << value << std::endl; };
};
```

You may build an `array` for each value, something like:

```
template <std::int16_t lowest, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr std::array<void (*)(), sizeof...(Is)>
make_x_functions(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return {&x<std::int16_t(lowest + Is)>::f...};
}

void call_x(std::int16_t i)
{
    constexpr std::int16_t lowest = -42;
    constexpr std::int16_t size = 100;
    constexpr auto arr = make_x_functions<lowest>(std::make_index_sequence<size>());

    if (lowest <= i && i < lowest + size)
    {
        arr[i - lowest]();
    }
}
```

Note that `std::index_sequence` is C++14, but may be written in C++11.

[Live example](https://ideone.com/0U0UPo)

But do you really want to use template if you use runtime value ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
switch(var)
{
case -32768: x<-32768>::do_something(); break;
case -32767: x<-32767>::do_something(); break;
case -32766: x<-32766>::do_something(); break;
case -32765: x<-32765>::do_something(); break;
/* ... */
case 32765: x<32765>::do_something(); break;
case 32766: x<32766>::do_something(); break;
case 32767: x<32767>::do_something(); break;
}
```

Templates are compile time. Instantiating a template requires generating code, which can only be done at compile time. What value `var` holds is only known at runtime (unless it is really a constant, but you didn't declare it as such).

I would consider a redesign. If you need this parameter to be variable, it should be a parameter to the function, not a template parameter. Otherwise you wind up with the above.

Comment: Note that a array equivalent to the switch may be generated using template.

Comment: Jarod42, would you please post a link on how to do it? I don't want for the whole range of int16_t, but for, say, an array of 100 entries.
Thanks.

Comment: @canellas: Added an answer for that.